# AngularJS, ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I study AngularJS and I can't understand what is the meanning of the expression inside the `ng-options` directive, here is a link to the [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/7b7KOXYCvwuwKfqTWkho?p=preview), what I can't understand following:

```
ng-options="net for net in networks"
```

I have looked at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) and the docs explained the expression above as:

> label for value in array

So there is the value attribute inside each option, the value represent the key in the array, my question is how the expression `net for net in networks` works I mean:

- I assume the first `net` is the key, and the second is the value, so the expression is "saying" take the key for that value inside the `netwroks` array and place it inside each value attribute of each option element.
- What I can't understand is how the `net for net` affect the `ng-model="network"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my simple interpretation of the docs for you:

`label` is the content of the option element displayed to the user.

`value` is the value placed in the ngModel binding when that option is selected, NOT the value attribute of the option element as you are assuming.

The value attribute of the option element is set by angular to the index of associated item in `array` (as you can see if you inspect the select elements in your plunker example).

**EDIT**:

You can think of `ng-options` as a `foreach` loop. Since `networks` is an array of strings in this case, `net` just becomes each string item in the array.

If networks was an array of objects, the situation would be different. Given `networks` looked like this instead:

```
var networks = [
    { id: 10, name: 'Verizon' },
    { id: 20, name: 'AT&T' },
    { id: 30, name: 'Sprint' },
];
```

`net` would become each object in the array. In this case you could use the expression `net.name for net in networks` to display the name of the network, but give the ngModel binding `network` the value of the object itself. If you wanted to use `id` as the value instead, you could use the expression `net.id as net.name for net in networks`. See the updated code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/recmDYjOdOvDrevsGu7k?p=preview).

Comment: Hi Taylor, thanks for the answer but I still don't understand how `net for net` affect anything, how the first `net` must be equal to the second `net`, can you explain the behavior, maybe if you can give me more details for how `net for net` is linking between `networks` and `ng-bind`.